# Are Selenium Implicit Wait times immutable?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium and while I was going through the docs and saw the below passage.

> 5.2. Implicit Waits

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0 (zero). Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object.

Does this mean that you cannot have multiple different implicit wait times in a program? Can you use implicit wait multiple times without it messing with the program?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple driver.implicitly_wait() in your program with varying waits.

Comment: Thanks! You also answered my find_element question but left that in a comment too. If you put that as an answer I will vote that up too.